# Inability to test the DPDK distributor application using the DPDK pktgen application in a virtual environment

Tags: pcap, dpdk

I'm trying to test the DPDK distributor using the DPDK pktgen application. I tried running a pcap file on port 0 as in the image below. Although the RX from pktgen is showing, nothing is being reflected on the port 0 of the distributor application

[DPDK pktgen screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd56p.jpg)

[DPDK distributor running with no packets in rx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAwwC.jpg)

the results were tested by having 2 ssh sessions with the virtual machine

I'm trying to test the DPDK distributor sample application by running a pcap file using DPDK pktgen application in a virtual environment. The specifications are as follows.

The host machine specifications:

- Ubuntu version: 22.04.1 LTS Jammy
- Cores: 8

The virtual machine is created using KVM and the specifications are as follows:

- Ubuntu version: 22.04.1 LTS Jammy
- Cores: 8
- Memory: 4096
- DPDK version: 22.07

I use ssht from the host machine to connect with the virtual machine. I have installed both the pktgen application and compiled the distributor sample application. I have 4 ports in my virtual machine and I disabled them from the kernel and enabled them for the DPDK as follows.

```
sudo ifconfig enp2s0 down && sudo modprobe uio && sudo modprobe uio_pci_generic && sudo dpdk-devbind.py -b uio_pci_generic 02:00.0 && sudo dpdk-devbind.py -b uio_pci_generic 08:00.0 && sudo dpdk-devbind.py -b uio_pci_generic 09:00.0
```

Then I navigated to dpdk-22.07/build/examples and started the distribtor application using.

```
sudo ./dpdk-distributor -l 0-4 -n 1 --file-prefix=p1 -- -p f
```

on a seperate ssh session with the virtual machine. I allocated more huge pages

```
$ sudo -i
# echo 1536 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages
/mnt# mount -t hugetlbfs pagesize=3GB /mnt/huge
```

Then started the pktgen application using,

```
sudo pktgen -l  5-6 -n 1 --file-prefix=p2 --proc-type auto --socket-mem 256  --  -P -m "[1:3].0" -s 0:smallFlows.pcap
```

But the RX for port 0 does not reflect the incoming packets from pktgen.

Comment: please update the following information 1) Pktgen started with the PCAP file, 2) PCAP file screen shot in wireshark or link to pcap file 3) NIC used for DPDK application

Comment: still waiting for answers from your end any updates?

Comment: find the pktgen started with the pcap file here https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd56p.jpg

Comment: Thank you very much for showing interest in the problem. Please find the nic types here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1izF13dQH6NurglvBNPMbfTFOM6lPsALa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The pcap was the small flows pcap from this link https://tcpreplay.appneta.com/wiki/captures.html but testing it for any pcap file would sufice

Comment: I am not able to see tx packets from pktgen with the pcap file you have mentioned in the screenshot. are you sending any packets? In small;lflow.pcap 90% of traffic is TCP and a couple of UDP. In packet-distributor example even though RSS is enabled for both TCP and udp there's only 1 rx-tx queue. Hence it should work. please update the question with diagram of your setup as it is not clear